# Autofilling form does not work on all browsers

Tags: html, autofill

I am trying to create an autofilling form for shippment details such as name, surname, street, postal code and so on. I want the form the autofil depending on the chosen "profile" - a data which was already filled in previously to avoid re-entering data if user uses the website many times. 
When filling in the form clicking on submit and afterwards going back to the order page, the autofill is not possible.

tried:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill
- https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Raw code, without any changes:

```
<form class="f-form f-form--basket checkout">
    <div class="f-form__col">
        <div class="f-field f-field--text">
            <label class="f-field__label" >
                First name
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="f-field__control"  name="firstName" placeholder="First name*" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="f-form__col">
        <div class="f-field f-field--text">
            <label class="f-field__label">
                Last name
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="f-field__control"  name="lastName" placeholder="Last name*" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="c-btn">
        Pay!
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I assume that when you say you have "tried" those links, you have altered your code to add the correct "autocomplete" HTML parameter to each element? When I did that to your code, it worked just fine for me. Autocomplete is very different browser-to-browser, and even user-to-user - Is it possible that you have altered the setting for yourself in your browser? Finally, remember that autocomplete doesn't fill the fields on page load - it "suggests" an autocomplete set of values *after* you start typing in one of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You said your goal was to "autofill" the empty form with "data which was already filled in previously". That's two separate ideas that seem to be getting crossed here:

The documentation pages you link to reference a browser feature called "Autofill", which is the idea that an individual user in their own workstation's browser can fill in information about themselves (demographic information like name and email, and shipping address information), and then the browser can help them fill in forms properly.

This sort of function would work well for you, if the fields you're trying to fill in are standard demographics fields. But in order for the users to take advantage of it, it's up to to the user to update their browser's preferences to set their own "Autofill profile" (you can't do that as the web developer from HTML/JS.

The second part of what you said referenced data "they already filled in"; presumably you mean information they filled in on your site, the first time through? In order to get that idea to work, you would need to save the information the user entered, somehow. You could either save the data client-side in a cookie or other HTML5 local storage option, and use Javascript to re-fill in those values when the user visits the page again, or if the user has an account with you and is logged in, you can save that data on the back-end and generate the HTML with the default values already filled-in, or build some other API endpoint to fetch their default values via Javascript/AJAX from the front-end.